# How to use string in arithmetic expression in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have written a simple script that grabs an ip in CDIR format from openstack. The line looks like this:

```
cidr="10.62.149.62/27"
```

I used awk to isolate just the IP, and then used awk one last time to store "27" in a variable called `POOL_SIZE`.

```
#!/bin/bash
NETWORK=$1
POOL=$( openstack subnet show --insecure $NETWORK -f shell|grep -w "cidr"|awk -F '"' '{print $2}'|awk -F '/' '{print $2}')
```

Now, I want to be able to subtract 1 from the 27 to get the value 26 and store in into a different variable.

```
POOL_SIZE=$(( $POOL - 1 ))
echo $POOL_SIZE
```

However, when I execute this script, I get this output:

```
- 1 ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

If I echo `$POOL` I get this output:

```
27
```

Therefore, I think that there is some character after "27" like a `\r` or `\n` that is causing the problem.

So, I want to be able to get rid of those extra characters and subtract 1 from 27.

How would I fix this?

Comment: `declare -p POOL` will let you see exactly what is contained in that variable, rather than echo which may mask your whitespace

Comment: `awk` is a heavy-handed solution for this. `ip=${cidr%/*}` is sufficient in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: The error message indicates that `POOL` ends with a carriage return.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the network, you can strip the address with

```
prefix_size=${cidr#*/}
```

and stript any trailing carriage return output by `openstack` with

```
prefix_size=${prefix_size%$'\r'}
```

`$'\r'` is a bash extension, so in other more limited POSIX shells you can use `tr` instead.

```
prefix_size=$(echo "$prefix_size" | tr -d '\r')
```

Or, save a carriage return to a variable once to use later:

```
cr=$(printf '\r')
...
prefix_size=${prefix_size%$cr}
```

Comment: @LucasWhitaker, if you click the checkbox next to this answer, that will mark your question resolved so it doesn't show up as still needing folks to look at it.